# Fill (color) part of image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

We are facing some problem in our project.We have some functionality which required to fill color to star image with some percentage.In our case their are five stars.All will be fill independently according to their percentage.

Suppose i have 5 stars,In which one star have 10% so it need to be fill up to some extent.Same as if 2nd star have 90% then it need to be fill up to maximum.Same as others stars also.So all stars are independents and will fill as per their %age.I have gone through all jquery plug ins but didn't find any solution.

Please let us know some solutions for this.
Thanks for your immediate reply.

Comment: Can you define more you problem with some html ?

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own stuff with a png mask that shows the background behind and than just fill the background according to the percentage.

Comment: Thanks Popa, but the problem is, i have a star image which i need to fill dynamically with color according to the percentage resulted from some calculation. Percentage may 10, 15, 50, 70 etc. Please see the attached star image which i need to fill with color dynamically. http://content.screencast.com/users/Amit28/folders/Default/media/37e74af7-3432-410e-abb5-be328cc3f1d9/Fill_Star.png

Comment: can u not change the image so the stars are "holes" ?